# How do I print text in colour? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("this text is blue")
```

How could I make the text blue?
I have:

```
print('\033[94m' + "this text is blue")
```

and

```
print("\033[94mthistextisblue")
```

However, nothing has worked so far.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: On Linux, both of your examples print blue text for me.

Comment: I'm using trinket

Comment: Trinket - Python 3

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to use the `colorama` module!

https://pypi.org/project/colorama/

https://github.com/tartley/colorama

It's compatible with all OSes. It's easy to use and much much safer than doing all of those special/exit etc characters by hand

Comment: Sadly, isn't working. I am using trinket.io - python 3. When I try to run the Colorama module it says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/b5114d4cc01b4ac1/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'

Comment: Thats because you have to install it first. I would suggest you learn how installing modules in python works. For example you can install it using command line: `pip install colorama`